# save path of image imported from gallery into sql database and display it in an imageview later

Tags: java, android, sql, imageview

I'm trying to save the path of an image imported from the gallery using this method:

```
case R.id.media:
        Intent i = new Intent(
                Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        return true;
```

Here is the on activity result method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        final Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = (cursor.getString(columnIndex));
        cursor.close();
        mImage = picturePath;
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.note_image);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        imageView.setClickable(true);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent viewImageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, selectedImage);
                        startActivity(viewImageIntent);
                    }
                });

    }


}
```

And here is the populate field method:

```
mImage =(note.getString(
                note.getColumnIndexOrThrow(NotesDbAdapter.KEY_IMAGE)));
```

But this is not working, the path doesnt get saved and when i close the activity and start the activity again, the image is gone. How can i fix this?

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would save the path. See the documentation http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html to get some ideas.